# Spring: can ResourceBundleMessageSource be configured to load properties in xml format

Tags: java, spring, properties, internationalization, resourcebundle

As you may know, properties are usually written in files in key=value format but can also be written in [XML](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29) [format](http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd).

The question is if (and how) can Spring's ResourceBundleMessageSource be configured to load properties in XML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring/1.2.9/spring-1.2.9-javadoc.jar!/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html). Seems it does support XML